# Pairing Rpi and windows PC for bluetooth over serial

Tags: raspbian-stretch, bluetooth, windows

I am currently working rpi 3B+ and windows system.
thing is I want to use bluetooth over serial to windows PC.
Before that happens RPI and Windows must be paired first, that is not happening at the moment. whenever I try to pair RPI to PC which is running win7. I get the error cannot install the drivers. I am using Raspbian stretch lite.

Comment: What do yo umean by Bluetooth over serial? Do yo uuse Serial Bluetooth adapter? Or you mean that you need to use Serial Port Profile to communicate with your RPi? If so you have to run server that implemens SPP on your RPi because by default there is no SPP service running on Raspberry/ The same about Windows. But on Windows side you need to create Incomming vCOM for Bluetooth connection.

Comment: I am following this link https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/bluetooth/serial-over-bluetooth  for that i need to pair both device and on Win PC have to select it as com port. but at the moment pc gets paired to RPI but their is no option to make it serial comm as suggested in the post. so at the moment i need to correctly pair these two.

Comment: Its not pairing issue. The problem is that RPi does not start RFCOMM server. Check your RPi config.